# Deploying KDB/Q as AWS Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, kdb

If I have KDB servers that can load up pretty rapidly and don't need to stay around more than 5 minutes, can I run them as AWS Lambda functions?

One problem I see is that these functions need to do analysis on a large kdb database.

There does not seem to be any way to get access to that database into a lambda function, other than copying the whole thing from S3 or some custom file server.

I'm worried if that MIGHT be too slow for my application.

Can the lambda function mount a block device? Or NFS mount a remote file system?

How would I do run Q as a Lambda? Wrapper then thing up in a supported language like nodejs, have the nodejs copy files from S3, then have the nodejs start the kdb instance with those (now) local files?

**Can I make multiple requests of a lambda function via Q's RPC or websockets?**